# App crashing on iPad but not simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, int, segue

My Application is crashing when I run it on the iPad but works 100% on the iPad simulator I am using Version 4.6.1 of Xcode and Version 6.1.3 on the iPad.
The problem lies where I am trying to pass the value of an int between segues

in my .h

```
@property (nonatomic, assign)int currentQuestion;
```

in my .m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"level1correct"]){
    AddLevel1IncorrectViewController *incorrect = [segue destinationViewController];
    incorrect.CQValue = self.currentQuestion;
}}
```

AddLevel1Incorrect.h

```
@property (nonatomic, assign)int CQValue;
```

AddLevel1Incorrect.m

```
@synthesize CQValue = _CQValue;

- (void)imageSelect{
int numItems = [arrayPath count];
NSMutableArray *left = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
NSMutableArray *right = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];

for (NSDictionary *itemData in arrayPath) {
    [left addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"L"]];
    [right addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"R"]];
}

NSLog(@" value of %d CQValue ", self.CQValue);
leftImageViewer.image = [UIImage imageNamed:left[self.CQValue]];//this is the point where the crash happens
rightImageViewer.image = [UIImage imageNamed:right[self.CQValue]];
}
```

The interesting thing is it does display the correct value in the NSLog in the Console as you will see at the top of the Crash Message

```
2013-04-03 22:50:00.404 thefyp[1506:907]  value of 1 CQValue 
2013-04-03 22:50:00.408 thefyp[1506:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is very brittle, meaning it makes a lot of assumptions about the data it's working with without verifying the data is accurate.

You never check the bounds of the array before you access it.  `self.CQValue` is 1, but in this case the array itself is empty.  so `left[self.CQValue]`, is `left[1]`, which is invalid.

Check `arrayPath` to make sure it's not empty.

Comment: How do should I check its not empty with an NSLog or if it exists?

Comment: Would that be the reason its crashing

Comment: It's crashing because CQValue is 1 but the array is empty.  For some reason arrayPath isn't getting set.

Comment: I do not think that is it as I have a function in viewDidLoad which loads the array once more 
`arrayPath = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Addition1" ofType:@"plist"]];
    [self imageSelect];`
I created an NSLog and it shows the complete contents of arrayPath correctly